# How to get rid of notice and warning in php form?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a `php` `form` when I click the only the `submit` button without selecting any options I don't want the system to display :

`Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\statistics\lecturer.php on line 83`

`Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\statistics\lecturer.php on line 83`

So I get the `notice` and the `warning` for this line of code: `while($unit=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))`, especially for the `$result`.

lecturer.php

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 include 'connect.php';

 $years = array(
    2005,
    2006,
    2007
 );
 $lecturers = array(
      'lec1',
      'lec2',
      'lec3',
      'lec4'
  );


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


$year = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
$lecturer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lecturer']);

/*checks if the user types the url of the page that he is not allowed to use, it leads him to the main page so to login*/
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){

    header("location:../../statistics/main.htm");
}
$username=$_SESSION['username'];


    if(!empty($lecturer) && !empty($year)){

        if (in_array($lecturer, $lecturers) && in_array($year, $years)) {

            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT unit_name,a1,a2,a3,l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,lavg,r1,r2,u1,u2,u3 FROM $lecturer WHERE year=$year)")or die(mysql_error());

            $result = mysql_query($sql);
        }

    else{
        echo "Please select a lecturer and a year.";
    }   
  }
}
?>
<html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../statistics/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
   <table id="table" width="900" border="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
    <td>Unit Name</td>
    <td>A1 </td>
    <td>A2 </td>
    <td>A3 </td>
    <td>L1 </td>
    <td>L2 </td>
    <td>L3 </td>
    <td>L4 </td>
    <td>L5 </td>
    <td>L6 </td>
    <td>L7 </td>
    <td>LAVG </td>
    <td>R1 </td>
    <td>R2 </td>
    <td>U1 </td>
    <td>U2 </td>
    <td>U3 </td>


</tr>

<?php
    while($unit=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['unit_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['a1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['a2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['a3']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l3']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l4']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l5']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l6']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l7']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['lavg']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['r1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['r2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['u1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['u2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['u3']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";    
    }
?>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i assume your code are in production phase and hiding all errors from displaying. Add these on top of php block:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 0);    // type of error for displaying
ini_set('display_errors', 0);     // 0 = hide errors; 1 = display errors
```

For testing phase, these codes below will show fatal error and hiding notice and warning:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);     // 0 = hide errors; 1 = display errors
```

Comment: This will result in not displaying any errors at all (also errors that you might need to know about). This should only be used when the complete site is done so others won't get background info of your site.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that you have tried to push ahead with the conditional section of your code without having all the values.

You are asking if the value is not empty which it is not but it is not empty with the value false because the post value was not set.

This is really helping you to write better code - you simply need to understand that there are missing conditions.

In your case take your line:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

and add a few additional constraints

```
if( (isset($_POST['submit'])) && (isset($_POST['year']))  && (isset($_POST['lecturer'])) ){
```

Now you have simple error checking and will ignore all input unless it is perfect.

However your end users will now complain that sometimes the form does not work. This is also helpful as it is telling you that you could do more with the conditionals

```
$noerrors = true;
if( !isset($_POST['year']) ){
    echo "Did you forget to choose a year?";
    $noerrors = false;
}
if( !isset($_POST['lecturer']) ){
    echo "Did you forget to choose a lecturer?";
    $noerrors = false;
}
if( isset($_POST['submit']) && $noerrors){
    //...
```

The basic "rule" of development that you need to remember is to assume that users will misuse the form or other UI you made and then code for every possible abuse and misuse. Starting from the assumption that someone aims to break your system is often helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

The query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `unit_name`, `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `l1`, `l2`, `l3`, `l4`, `l5`, `l6`, `l7`, `lavg`, `r1`, `r2`, `u1`, `u2`, `u3` FROM `$lecturer` WHERE `year` = $year)") or die (mysql_error());
```

The backticks will prevent an error know as `mysql reserved words`

For the while loop do the following:

```
if(!empty($result)) {
        while($unit = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$unit['unit_name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$unit['a1']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$unit['a2']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$unit['a3']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$unit['l1']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$unit['l2']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$unit['l3']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$unit['l4']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$unit['l5']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$unit['l6']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$unit['l7']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$unit['lavg']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$unit['r1']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$unit['r2']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$unit['u1']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$unit['u2']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$unit['u3']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";    
        }
    }
```

If you still get the error / warning echo the `$result` just before the if statement. and let me know what you get. While trying this remove the 2 lines from @EngCy.

You should also start using `mysqli_*` or `pdo` as `mysql_*` is depracted and will be removed

***Update***

I looked at the code again and noticed a other error:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT unit_name,a1,a2,a3,l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,lavg,r1,r2,u1,u2,u3 FROM $lecturer WHERE year=$year)")or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

You are basically doing the same here. You first do a query to and set the result to `$sql`. And when that is done you query `$sql` this wont work. So you can use `$sql` in your while loop or say `$result = $sql;`

Comment: I did exactly what you told me, but I get this error : 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1'. I now removed the backticks and I also removed the 'if' condition before the 'while' and it works now.